# Is there any way to prevent someone from running a shell as root?

Tags: sudo, root, audit, doas

This is a question I've pondered for a long time and thought was impossible.

Is it possible to prevent administrators of a machine from bypassing the audit capabilities of `sudo` or `doas`? For instance, running `sudo su -` and having a root shell?

I suppose the real question is, is there a way to audit root's activity on a machine?

Comment: Don't add the user to the `sudo` group. If you have a real problem, please tell us. Otherwise the answer will only be *don't give administrative rights to users that should not have administrative rights*. Please also check: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: logging root activity is done outside the box: you connect as normal and explicit user from a special host that will log all keyboard (or windows ) activities, only security team can view audit file.

Comment: This question is too vague to give a good answer.  For example one answer is don't give "someone" any access to root at all.  If you want for example someone to log in as root but not have a shell (let's say to do sftp only) there are ways do to that.  You can put /sbin/nologin as the shell for that user.  However since we do not know what your use case is, there is no best answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to prevent administrators of a machine from bypassing the audit capabilities of sudo or doas?

By definition, *administrators* of a machine have full access to *everything* within the machine, so they'll also be able to stop the audit process, tamper with the audit logfiles, etc.

If you need to monitor/audit someone, don't give them root access; rather, add the user to the sudoers file, allowing them the minimum set of commands necessary to accomplish their duties.

Answer (score -3):

We can put a plug on the root:

```
sudo chsh root
```

And put the plug: `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false`
Necessarily with `sudo`.
**Warning:** Otherwise then we will not be able to change the settings back.

Or on my Fedora system, there is a directory for scripts that starts at login time: `/etc/profile.d`. Let's create a script `custom`.
Arrange ID verification:

```bsh
if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then
    exit
fi
```

```
ls -l /etc/profile.d/custom

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root ...
```

You can also delete this file with `sudo` and execute other commands with `sudo`, but you will not be able to start the shell:

```
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/custom
```

Comment: This does not prevent `sudo /bin/bash`